# Quantification du pronom « se » au pluriel

Tags: sens, pluriel, pronoms-réfléchis, pronoms-reciproques

Si on dit  « Les politiciens ne s'aiment pas », est-ce que cela signifie 1 ou 2 (ci-dessous), ou les deux avec ambiguïté, ou autre chose ?

1. Soit x, un politicien, alors x ne s'aime pas. (x n'aime pas x)
2. Soient x et y, des politiciens, alors x n'aime pas y et y n'aime pas x.

(En anglais, on dit *themselves* et *each other* respectivement pour les deux.)

Comment: vraiment, en anglais "themselves" a d'ambiguité et "each other" signifie (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Les politiciens ne s'aiment pas entre eux.
>
> Les politiciens ne s'aiment pas l'un l'autre.

Pour un sens réciproque.

> Les politiciens ne s'aiment pas eux-mêmes.

Pour un sens réflexif, mais cette formulation garde une ambiguïté entre un sens collectif (le groupe des politiciens n'aime pas le groupe des politiciens) et un sens individuel (chaque individu politicien ne s'aime pas lui-même).

Answer (score 3):

Cela peut vouloir dire les deux (aussi bien qu'ils ne s'aiment pas eux-mêmes ou qu'ils ne s'aiment pas les uns les autres). Le contexte est important.
Cependant, sans contexte, "les politiciens ne s'aiment pas" implique plus "les uns les autres" que "ne s'aiment pas eux-mêmes".